# Why are all my UIAlertView labels/text bold by default in iOS 8

Tags: ios8, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

I searched for this and the only solutions seem to be derive from the UIAlertViewDelegate.  I don't want to do that just to eliminate bold text.

The code that I use to pop my alert view is the following:

```
NSString* errPrompt = @"some text here, anything that will not show bold :)";
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                message:errPrompt
                                                delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:[self getUiText:"OK"]
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in iOS and affects all alerts which do not have a title set.

Interestingly most standard iOS alerts (like in App Store) are not affected.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on iOS 8. Just empty string in the title without space inside @"".

```
  [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
     message:@"My message" 
     delegate:nil
     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
     otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you do not set Alert title. (Weird, I know)

Set Alert's title as. empty if you. do not want to add any title

```
UIAlertController(title: "", message: "The alert message", preferredStyle: .alert)
```